# Why hibernate acquire connection even after l2 cache hits?

Tags: hibernate, ehcache, hikaricp

I use ehcache with hibernate with spring data. As a connection pool I use hikaricp.

Here are the hibernate logs for one query:

```
2016-04-24 17:03:16 INFO  [qtp603358340-29] StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener: Session Metrics {
    0 nanoseconds spent acquiring 0 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent preparing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    89979 nanoseconds spent performing 41 L2C hits;
    3214 nanoseconds spent performing 1 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
2016-04-24 17:03:16 INFO  [qtp603358340-29] StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener: Session Metrics {
    116282684 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent preparing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
```

As you see l2 cache works nice, but hibernate acquires the connection anyway and it takes too long, because DB is well... slow and bad. Don't think about DB, just tell me, why after l2 hits, hibernate tries to acquire connection anyway? Is it possible to force him not to do it? Maybe something wrong with my connection pool as well?

Comment: That's a great question. It's surprising no one has answered it yet. I faced the same issue and I haven't found the reason for this phenomenon. Have you managed to clarify it?